# Need help installing gcc and g++-4.7 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gcc, g++

Hi I need help installing gcc and g++ -4.7 in order to install matcaffe for my research project. I have tried to install from terminal directly using sudo apt-get install like other post suggest but it doesn't work for me

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7 g++-4.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.7-base' for regex 'gcc-4.7'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.7-hppa64' for regex 'gcc-4.7'
E: Unable to locate package g++-4.7
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'g++-4.7'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'g++-4.7'
```

Some post suggest to directly download but since I am new to ubuntu I have no idea with which architecture I should download from [gcc](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gcc-4.7) and [g++](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/g++-4.7). Please help me resolve this.

A little bit of backstory, I already succeed to run make matcaffe but I got error on mattest So I tried to follow the warning which shows up during make matcaffe which is to try using gcc and g++ 4.7. So a little bit of topic but if someone succeed on installing matcaffe on ubuntu 18.04 I would like to read their comment here. If not allowed I will make a new topic about it

Comment: The packages you link are for 16.04; you are running 18.04.

Comment: Yeah I know, but that is what the matcaffe wants so I tried to follow since I fail during mattest and trying to resolve it

Comment: How about just installing 16.04?

Comment: I am considering about it if that is the only way to work with it because installing caffe is already painful experience on 18.04 don't know if it will work the same way on 16.04 not to mention I am not sure if it will resolve the mattest problem or not

Comment: Well, all I know is that on 16.04 you can install gcc/g++ 4.7 easily from the repositories (like you tried to do unsuccessfully on 18.04).

Comment: I see, thank you. I will keep it in mind